# Setting a DataGrid background color based on the previous row

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to setup a grid where I do column sorting, but I wanted to do zebra striping, only rather than every other row or every x rows, I want it to be based on the value of the previous row. i.e. All rows that contain 0 have a blue background, the next value would have a white background, the next value would be blue, etc....

The problem I have is that I can't seem to find where to actually do the setting of the background colors. I'm using a custom sorter and I tried setting it in there after I re-order the list and set the data source, but it appears that when the data source is set, that the rows don't exist yet. I tried using the DataContextChanged, but that event doesn't seem to be firing.

Here is what I have now.

```
namespace Foo.Bar
{
  public partial class FooBar
  {
    List<Bla> ResultList { get; set; }
    SolidColorBrush stripeOneColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold);
    SolidColorBrush stripeTwoColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

    //*********************************************************************************************
    public Consistency()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    //*********************************************************************************************
    override protected void PopulateTabWithData()
    {
      ResultList = GetBlas();
      SortAndGroup("Source");
    }

    //*********************************************************************************************
    private void SortAndGroup(string colName)
    {
      IOrderedEnumerable <Bla> ordered = null;
      switch (colName)
      {
        case "Source":
        case "ID":
          ordered = ResultList.OrderBy(r => r.Source).ThenBy(r => r.ID);
          break;
        case "Name":
          ordered = ResultList.OrderBy(r => r.Source).ThenBy(r => r.Name);
          break;
        case "Message":
          ordered = ResultList.OrderBy(r => r.Message);
          break;
        default:
          throw new Exception(colName);
      }

      ResultList = ordered.ThenBy(r => r.Source).ThenBy(r => r.ID).ToList(); // tie-breakers
      consistencyDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
      consistencyDataGrid.ItemsSource = ResultList;
      ColorRows();
    }

    //*********************************************************************************************
    private void consistencyDataGrid_Sorting(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
      SortAndGroup(e.Column.Header.ToString());
      e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void ColorRows()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < ResultList.Count; i++)
  {
    var currentItem = ResultList[i];
    var row = myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(currentItem) as DataGridRow;
    if (row == null)
    {
      continue;
    }
    if (i > 0)
    {
      var previousItem = ResultList[i - 1];
      var previousRow = myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(previousItem) as DataGridRow;
      if (currentItem.Source == previousItem.Source)
      {
        row.Background = previousRow.Background;
      }
      else
      {
        if (previousRow.Background == stripeOneColor)
        {
          row.Background = stripeTwoColor;
        }
        else
        {
          row.Background = stripeOneColor;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      row.Background = stripeOneColor;
    }
  }
}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if your rowcolor is based of any row value you can simply use a cell style to set your row background color

Comment: In this case I don't care what the value of the cell/row is, I only care if it differs from the previous cell/row. So what I really want is striping, not a value based coloration.

Comment: Then fix the question as you state "I want it to be based on the value of cells".  And be clear on if you want to color cells or rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a handler for LoadingRow and place your color logic there:

```
bool isColorOne = false;
var previousValue = null;
private consistencyDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Check current value against previous value
    if (previousValue == e...)
    {
        previousValue = e...;
        isColorOne = !isColorOne;
    }
    if (isColorOne)
    {
        row.Background = stripeOneColor;
    }
    else
    {
        row.Background = stripeTwoColor;
    }
}
```

Then you can reset values for `isColorOne` and `previousValue` as necessary on sorting.

Comment: @Maslow I would not think that possible since, when setting up a Template for an item, it does not know about any other items. Closest I could see coming is add some color property to the bound object, set the color when constructing the object based on whatever rules you need, and then use a binding to that color property in the xaml.

Comment: does this account at all for virtualization? I'm having issues with it

Comment: @Maslow From my understanding it should behave the same as having specified a Background setting. Do you notice your application behaving any different with `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"`?